# I'm running Android 4.3 on Virtual Box in Ubuntu 13.10,could it harm my pc or disc?

Tags: virtualbox, android

I have that doubt,'cause I think Android is made for ssd and mine is hdd. I'm doing it for being able to run Whatsapp,it appears to work fine, do you think that when Ubuntu touch will be running Whatsapp we will be able to run it on Ubuntu pc too? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, although Android is optimized for SSD, it will not harm your HDD. As to the Whatsapp Touch app, I don't know.